# Javascript - change div after page load

Tags: javascript

I have a div that renders automatically by a plugin, I want after the page has loaded, I can cut it from a place and put it inside the div that contains my image:

to exemplify I made this codepen, I want to change the div 'change-place' into the div 'contain-image'

[Code pen](https://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/rNYJYgP)

in short I want to make a javascript that takes the blue div out of the red one and puts it inside the green one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.contain-image').append($('.change-place'));
});
```

Comment: Your codepen fails because it does not include jQuery. See error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works ... you have to add:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to use Vanilla JS code I upload this example.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", myFunc);

function myFunc() {
    let el = document.querySelector('.change-place');
    document.querySelector('.contain-image').appendChild(el);
};
```

```css
.contain-image {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #00ff00;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.minha-imagem {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.dolado {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff0000;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.change-place {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #0000ff;
    display: inline-flex;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='contain-image'>
    <div>
        <h1>contem titulo</h1>
    </div>
    <div><img class="minha-imagem" alt="" src="" /></div>
    <div><button>botão</button></div>
</div>
<div class="dolado">
    <div class='change-place'>teste</div>
</div>
```